# css body filter invert not working for pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-filters

I am trying to invert the colors using css `filter` property. I have applied `filter:invert(100%)` in body. I want filter property should not affect `<img />` element. I have added css `:not(img)` in `body`. But, it won't work.

```css
.aaa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00a3fe;
  margin: 5px
}
body:not(img) {
  filter: invert(90%)
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">

</div><div class="aaa">

</div>

<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/birds_PNG115.png" />
```

Comment: `body:not(img) {`  => `body :not(img) {` ... you need to put a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing space on the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) so `body:not(img)` is equivalent to `body` and it's applying for the body tag itself.

```css
.aaa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00a3fe;
  margin: 5px
}
body :not(img) {
/*--^^^----*/
  filter: invert(90%)
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">

</div><div class="aaa">

</div>

<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/birds_PNG115.png" />
```

---

**UPDATE :** Even in previous case it will cause issues when there are children elements so it's better to apply it for the body and apply the image as well so it will revert back.

```css
.aaa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00a3fe;
  margin: 5px
}

body {
  filter: invert(90%)
}

body img {
  filter: invert(90%)
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">

</div>
<div class="aaa">

</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/birds_PNG115.png" />
</div>
```

Or you have to apply filter specifically to element instead of wildcard selecting.

Comment: Here, In this simple case it is working. But, In large files/projects its not working `body :not(img)`

Comment: @KaruppiahRK may be the parent element gets the style applied

Comment: In that case, what is the solution?

Comment: @KaruppiahRK : apply twice to revert ..... check the update

Comment: that *applies* the `filter` twice actually... @KaruppiahRK apply the `filter` specifically to the elements that you need, if you apply it to a *parent element* it gets applied to the *child elements* too...

Comment: @kukkuz No. I want to apply it to a parent element. In my case, That is the only possible way to achieve it. I have more than 10000 of css classes. So, its really hard to specify the filter for particular elements.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK filter is like opacity, if applied to the parent, you cannot revert it on child element. Applying the filter again, will not give the initial result.